# Understanding IPV4 address range

Tags: ipv4, firewall, ip-address, ip-range

I do have basic understanding of IP Address  which is unique  address for each System either in an organization or over the internet. But i want to understand what is IP address range

Lets Say we have below IP'S in my company

1. 10.110.80.9
2. 10.145.60.4
3. 10.450.90.10

Will 10.0.0.0 represent IP range of my organization or it should be something like  10.0.0.0/16

I have few questions or clarification

1. I am not aware of significance of value after / , i have seen IP address range like 10.230.8.6/22
   what does /16 or /22 represent
2. If i set firewall rule to allow communication for all IPs of my compnay will below IP address range take
   care of it 
   10.0.0.0/16 . should i assume that any IP address that start with 10. will be part of this address range ?

Comment: See [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) to the above linked question.

Answer (score 0):

The number behind the / is the prefix length. /16 means, that 16 bits of the ip address are the network portion, and 16 bits are used to address hosts. It tells you which bits of the subnet mask are set to 1.

/16 can also be written as:

11111111.11111111.00000000.00000000

And when you translate this to decimal:

255.255.0.0

Try the same with /22 or /8 or /29 or /24

Answer (score 0):

Generally private ip ranges address are in between

`10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255 172.16.0.9 to 172.31.255.255 192.168.0.0 -192.168.255.255`

Above mentioned private address range can be used in organising for allocation of ip addres to servers PC s and cameras and network devices

To understand significance of 10.230.8.6/22 , ip address and subnet mask concepts has to be reviewed

/22 is subnet mask .

**Subnetting**

Subnet mask desides length of ip address range , Subnet mask is a mask used to determine what subnet an IP address belongs to. An IP address has two components, the network address and the host address. For example, consider the IP address 172.16.10.5 Assuming this is part of a Class B network, the first two numbers (172.16) represent the Class B network address, and the second two numbers (10.5) identify a particular host on this network